# How to install a two-way coax wall outlet for home internet and TV?

Tags: television, data-wiring, coaxial-cable

I want to install coaxial wall outlets throughout my home. The only ones I was able to find are these two-way outlets, with a male and a female connector. What I find confusing is that the outlet also has two places where you can insert the cable, one with an arrow pointing down (away, like an output) and another pointing up (inwards, like an input).

So my questions are:

- Why are there both male and female connectors?
- Why are there two places to insert the coaxial cable? What do the in/up and out/down arrows represent, and when would you use either?
- I use this cable for internet and TV connections. Should I use the in/up connection?
- Will both the male and female connectors work simultaneously? Can I have a TV and a router connected to the same wall outlet?

[image: The coaxial wall outlet I purchased]

Comment: The in/up is from the cable company, the out/down is to tv.

Comment: Can you please clarify? What do you mean to TV?

Comment: The out port goes to something in the house.  TV was probably bad wording on my part, probably goes to a router first.

Comment: Not a style of coaxial connector I recognize...

Comment: Where in the world do you live? That looks nothing like the standard TV/Internet coax jack found in the USA.

Comment: Dutch: https://webshop.oosterberg.nl/producten/edc-1000-g-hirschmann-coax-wcd-inb-fm-tv-digt-ret/10509200

Comment: @Huesmann Correct. Although, these wall plates are made in Spain.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking exactly.    The coax coming into your house is your "in-line".    This needs to go into a modem or a router (with built in modem abilities).    Either works.    From there you go out ethernet connections or wireless.    So the router is a hub spoke configuration.     To add to the complexity you can convert your house's coax system to ethernet (I did this a few years ago) but you need to have a converter on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that thing (?) you have, use a [simple wall mount F barrel connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B92JBPDX), no box needed.  Use [quad-shielded RG6 coax cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W2TZLC4) cut to length and attach [male F connectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0996914XT) to each end.
You will need to design the distribution system (splitters, possibly bidirectional amplifiers for cable boxes, etc.).
If you're wanting to run data lines from your cable modem, you would use UTP instead of coax, changing everything.

Comment: My internet subscription comes over coax, which goes into the modem, which then goes to the router. Thank you for the effort, but your answer is not useful to me since it applies to a different situation than what I described. Maybe it'll help someone else.